# Error: segmentation fault while inserting more element to BST using iterative method

Tags: c

I am trying  to implement the BST in iterative method using c programming. Inserting only one element will not cause segmentation error(2nd line in main function root = insert(root,50). But adding more than one element in BST shows segmentation error. I don't know where the mistake. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct bstnode
{
    int data;
    struct bstnode *left;
    struct bstnode *right;
};



struct bstnode* getnode(int data)
{
   
    struct bstnode *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode));
    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed");
    }
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode *root,int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = getnode(data);
        return root;
    }
     
    struct bstnode *temp = root;
    struct bstnode *parent;
    int flag;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
       parent = temp; 
       if(data < temp->data)
       {
           temp = temp->left;
           flag = 1;
       }
       if(data > temp->data)
       {
           temp = temp->right;
           flag = 0;
       }
    }
    
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        parent->left = getnode(data);
    }
    else
        parent->right = getnode(data);
     
     return root; 
    
}

void inorder(struct bstnode* root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("%d \n", root->data);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct bstnode *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 50);
    insert(root, 30);
    insert(root, 20);
    insert(root, 40);
    insert(root, 70);
    insert(root, 60);
    insert(root, 80);
    
    inorder(root);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The purpose of checks like this: `if(temp == NULL)` is to avoid accessing `NULL` pointers. You only print a warning and then continue to dereference the pointer anyway. That's not how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My intension  was that even if the memory is not allocated it should print the "failed" comment then it should show segmentation fault. but it only shows segmentation fault comment.

Comment: If the memory is not allocated, you invoke undefined behaviour which may or may not cause a crash. Normally people try to avoid that. ;)

Comment: thanks, i will keep it in mind that :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think what happens here when `data` is less than `temp->data` and `temp->left` is `NULL`?

```
   if(data < temp->data)
   {
       temp = temp->left;
       flag = 1;
   }
   if(data > temp->data)
   {
       temp = temp->right;
       flag = 0;
   }
```

You probably want to do an `else if` instead of just `if` in this case.

Also what happens if `data` is equal to `temp->data`?